# Can I flag a question for deletion even if it was answered?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'd like a question deleted since the problem was solved and the situation was probably unique so it is probably not relevant for anybody anymore:

[How to make Quartus II find the Altera DE2 board?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38446/how-to-make-quartus-ii-find-the-altera-de2-board)

I think that the question can be deleted because it is no longer a problem and was a random error that is no longer appearing. Is that ok?

Answer (score 3):

If you press the delete button and press OK the next prompt you'll get is:

> Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead.

I can't speak for the moderators (that flag would be handled by diamond moderators) but would guess they'd be hesistant to delete it because while it's been solved for you it might be useful to future visitors. The view count of 717 over the past year isn't huge but I've seen questions with a much lower view count that have helped me.

In fact only today I searched for something that threw up a StackOverflow page that was over two years old and didn't have any votes on the question or the answer that helped me so I upvoted both. That involved a technology pretty much obsolete for close to ten years which is probably why it wasn't popular, but it gave me a quick solution to maintaining some legacy code.

Answer (score 3):

1. You never can tell if somebody else will encounter the same or a similar problem.
2. The answers have upvotes, so the question won't be bumped by "community". It will remain in the background, where it won't annoy anybody.
3. Most questions get solved in the end. Would you like to have all those deleted as well?

I don't see why it should be deleted.